# Set Style property for an element from string containing HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an HTML string containing elements like `button`, `li`, `span` etc.

I want to apply some styles to buttons based on their class name.

ex: if

```
button.btn {
   some styles
}
```

and

```
button.btn-success {
    some other styles
}
```

After adding styles I have to add this html string to body. How can I do this in Jquery. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I hope you are aware of css style attributes,First add styles as you like then write script to add to the body.

Comment: Search for `inline css styling`. You will understand how to do. It is simple.

Comment: actually my requirement is to send mail body. I have to add style attribute for content in mail body as it will not accept bootstrap classes.So, that html string i am getting dynamically in js and i have to check for classes and add css to elements. after doing that i have to append the modified html string to mail body. Note: i have HTML string not the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$('button').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("btn")){

    // add style here
    }

    if($(this).hasClass("btn-success")){

    // add style here
    }
});
```

Comment: Its is not DOM. if its a DOM we can use above method. I have html string.